# Spark Submit failure on EMR - _"java.lang.IllegalStateException: ... make sure Spark is built."_

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, amazon-emr

I can't submit a Spark job via spark-submit on EMR. My spark-submit looks like below -

```
sudo spark-submit --class timeusage.TimeUsage \
--deploy-mode cluster --master yarn \
--num-executors 2 --conf spark.executor.cores=2 \
--conf spark.executor.memory=2g --conf spark.driver.memory=1g \
--conf spark.driver.cores=1 --conf spark.logConf=true \
--conf spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.SPARKMASTER=yarn \
--conf spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.WAREHOUSEDIR=s3a://whbucket/spark-warehouse \
--conf spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.S3AACCESSKEY=xxx \
--conf spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.S3ASECRETKEY=yyy \
--jars s3://bucket/week3-assembly-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar \
s3:/bucket/week3-assembly-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar \
s3a://sbucket/atussum.csv
```

The error looks like below -

```
19/06/04 07:36:59 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 1.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 2, ip-172-31-66-110.ec2.internal, executor 1): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at timeusage.TimeUsage$$anonfun$8.apply(TimeUsage.scala:70)
    at timeusage.TimeUsage$$anonfun$8.apply(TimeUsage.scala:70)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:410)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:410)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:410)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$13.hasNext(Iterator.scala:463)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.agg_doAggregateWithKeys_0$(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$11$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:619)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:125)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:402)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:408)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Library directory '/mnt/yarn/usercache/root/appcache/application_1559614942233_0036/container_1559614942233_0036_02_000002/assembly/target/scala-2.11/jars' does not exist; make sure Spark is built.
    at org.apache.spark.launcher.CommandBuilderUtils.checkState(CommandBuilderUtils.java:248)
    at org.apache.spark.launcher.CommandBuilderUtils.findJarsDir(CommandBuilderUtils.java:342)
    at org.apache.spark.launcher.YarnCommandBuilderUtils$.findJarsDir(YarnCommandBuilderUtils.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.prepareLocalResources(Client.scala:543)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.createContainerLaunchContext(Client.scala:863)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.submitApplication(Client.scala:177)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend.start(YarnClientSchedulerBackend.scala:57)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl.start(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:178)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:501)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala:2520)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$7.apply(SparkSession.scala:936)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$7.apply(SparkSession.scala:927)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:927)
    at timeusage.TimeUsage$.<init>(TimeUsage.scala:23)
    at timeusage.TimeUsage$.<clinit>(TimeUsage.scala)
    ... 23 more
```

I've verified that my project's build dependencies are all correct. And the project works on local[*].
This is the first time I'm working with a multi-module SBT project - I'm not sure if this has something to do with it?
I've added the Assembly JAR to be executed to the --jars config but it hasn't had any impact at all.

My build.sbt is here - https://github.com/kevvo83/scala-spark-ln/blob/master/build.sbt

The expected result is that the project runs to completion and creates Hive tables in S3.
I'm still investigating, and will post updates in here as soon as I have them.

---

After Harsh's answer, I've added these 2 lines to my spark-submit command -

```
--files /usr/lib/spark/conf/hive-site.xml \
--jars s3://bucket/week3-assembly-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar \
```

Now the stacktrace error is -

```
19/06/06 10:37:55 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 1.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 2, ip-172-31-76-146.ec2.internal, executor 1): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class *timeusage.TimeUsage*$
    at timeusage.TimeUsage$$anonfun$8.apply(TimeUsage.scala:70)
    at timeusage.TimeUsage$$anonfun$8.apply(TimeUsage.scala:70)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:410)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:410)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:410)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$13.hasNext(Iterator.scala:463)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.agg_doAggregateWithKeys_0$(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$11$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:619)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:125)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:402)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:408)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

(FYI timeusage.TimeUsage is my class in the JAR). Is there anything else I need to include to ensure my class defs are getting pickedup?

---

UPDATE: I've got this to work - I believe the last 3 confs in the code snippet below are what worked (based on how the docs say that Spark loads Jars into staging area on HDFS for the Executors to access).

```
--conf spark.executorEnv.SPARK_HOME=/usr/lib/spark/
--conf spark.yarn.jars=/usr/lib/spark/jars/*.jar
--conf spark.network.timeout=600000
--files /usr/lib/spark/conf/spark-defaults.conf
```

Further, the spark-submit executes the Jar from local disk - and not from S3 bucket as how I was wrongly doing it earlier.

Marking the answer as correct, as it put me on the right track to resolving it.

Comment: what's the emr label you are using?

Comment: The EMR label i'm using is the latest one: **emr-5.23.0**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are running the spark-submit in yarn master mode, you will need to pass hive-site.xml as files argument in your command :

```
sudo spark-submit --class timeusage.TimeUsage \
--deploy-mode cluster --master yarn \
--num-executors 2 --conf spark.executor.cores=2 \
--conf spark.executor.memory=2g --conf spark.driver.memory=1g \
--conf spark.driver.cores=1 --conf spark.logConf=true \
--conf spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.SPARKMASTER=yarn \
--conf spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.WAREHOUSEDIR=s3a://whbucket/spark-warehouse \
--conf spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.S3AACCESSKEY=xxx \
--conf spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.S3ASECRETKEY=yyy \
--jars s3://bucket/week3-assembly-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar \
--files /usr/lib/spark/conf/hive-site.xml \
s3:/bucket/week3-assembly-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar \
s3a://sbucket/atussum.csv
```

Comment: Your comment helped - I've added these 2 lines to my spark-submit, -

Now I'm getting a `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class timeusage.TimeUsage$`. I thought the `--jars` should have taken care of the classpaths on the Driver and Executors.

I'm still looking into getting this to run.

Comment: are you getting any logs like this when you execute spark-submit : Warning: Skip remote jar s3://myBucket/....

Comment: AFAIK the jar must be local, you will need to download the jar on local hdfs (EMRs) and then pass that to spark-submit.